# (iphone) Is having many AVAudioPlayer instance fine?

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

For my small game, I'd like to play effect sound for various scenario.
Mostly it will be user-interaction related.

I may need to play multiple sounds at one time.

I'm planning to allocate AVAudioPlayer for each sound.
I wonder a viewController having about 10-20 AVAudioPlayers is fine.
(sound data itself is rather small, less than 100k in aac)

I just feel that declaring 10-20 AVAudioPlayer instance in a class seems weird.
Is there a better way of doing it or am I just over-thinking it?

Answer (score 0):

I think OpenAL is a better option in such situations. Dont worry if you dont know it. There is a great video tutorial here (with source code): http://www.71squared.com/2009/05/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-9-sound-manager/

To find more you can visit: 
http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's fine to have many `AVAudioPlayer` instances. I don't know how many the limit is but it's definitely more than a dozen.

Here are some gotchas:

`AVAudioPlayer` doesn't do level mixing, so if your sounds are high volume, they may end up constructively interfering with each other and causing waveform distortion. I set a maximum volume of 0.8 to try to work around this, but it's not reliable.

If you try to start them all at the same time, using the `play` method may end up starting them out of sync. Instead, figure out a time soon enough that the user won't notice, but far enough away that it gives your code time to exit and `AVFoundation` time to get ready.  Then use `[player playAtTime:soon]`.

Here's some code that's working for me now. YMMV:

```
-(void)play
{
    BOOL success;

    AVAudioPlayer *player = self.player;

    player.numberOfLoops = -1;
    player.currentTime = 0;
    player.volume = _volume;

    // NSLog(@"deviceCurrentTime=%f", player.deviceCurrentTime);

    static double soon = 0;
    if (soon < player.deviceCurrentTime) {
        soon = player.deviceCurrentTime + 0.5; // why so flakey???
    }
    success = [player playAtTime:soon]; // too flakey for now

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"player %@ FAILED", player);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"player %@ %@ playing at: %f", player, [[player.url relativePath] lastPathComponent], soon);
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure if my "`soon`" var is thread-safe, and you should adjust the slop until it works for you... `0.1` was too fast for me at some point or other so I bumped it up to `0.5`.)